# STM32 bootloader timing for BOOT0 and nRESET needed

Tags: stm32, reset, bootloader, timing

I need to know the timing constraints for STM32 bootloading (over UART).  How long must \RESET be held low to reset?  How long must BOOT0 remain high after \RESET is released?  I need this for the STM32L4P5, the STM32F423, and the STM32G031.   I apologize in advance, since it is certainly published somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in **Reference Manual** section 2.6 **Boot Configuration**

*The values on the BOOT pins are latched on the 4th rising edge of SYSCLK after a reset. It
is up to the user to set the BOOT1 and BOOT0 pins after reset to select the required boot
mode.*

EDIT:
For those can't find **SYSCLK** check out **RCC** section or watch STM32CubeMX **Clock Configuration** tab

**SYSCLK** is output of clock multiplexer before clock divider that change it into HCLK
[image]

Comment: For the STM32L4x, the manual has, "the 4th edge of the internal startup clock source after reset release."  The phrase "startup clock" is never repeated again.  Is it SYSCLK, something else, a trade secret?

Comment: You can provide your specific part number for better answer, but in general all STM32 microcontrollers has a internal clock that called **HSI**, so when microcontroller power up first system use this clock as a **SYSCLK** then in **SystemClock_Config** function user can change source of **SYSCLK** to another clock such as **HSE** or **PLL**

Comment: For better understanding you can read **RCC** section or watch STM32CubeMX **Clock Configuration** tab

Comment: All that configures **SYSCLK**.  But the STM32L4x manual does not state that SYSCLK is used.  It says **internal startup clock**.  It is never stated that the internal startup clock is SYSCLK.  A clock called the "Wakeup from Stop clock" can be set via `RCC_CFGR[STOPWUCK]` to MSI or HSI16.  Maybe that is the clock?